# How to make characters in a string repeat using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I make individual characters within a string repeat a given amount of times?

That is, how do I turn "XyZ" into "XXXyyyZZZ"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

```js
var foo = 'bar';

function makeString(str, repeat) {
  var str = Array.prototype.map.call(str, function(character) {
    var nascentStr = '';
    while (nascentStr.length < repeat) {
      nascentStr += character;
    }
    return nascentStr;
  }).join('');
  return str;
}

alert(makeString(foo, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of a few functions.  First you'll need to split the string into individual characters:

```
var charArray = "XyZ".split('');
```

Once you have it split up, you can use a combination of the `.map` function and a nifty little trick of javascript `Array`.

```
var someMultiplier = 5;
var duplicatedArray = charArray.map(function(char) {
  return Array(someMultiplier).join(char);
});
```

At that point, you have an array of strings that have the duplicate letters, and you can combine them back with `.join`

```
var dupString = duplicatedArray.join('');
dupString === "XXXXXyyyyyZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not mentioned what will happen if input will be like `xyxzy`. Assuming it will be `xxxyyxxxzzzyyy`

```
// function takes input string & num of repitation
function buildString(input, num) {
    var _currentChar = ""; // Final output string
    for (var m = 0; m < input.length; m++) {
        //call another function which will return XXX or yyy or zzz & then finally concat it
        _currentChar += _repeatString((input.charAt(m)), num);
    }
}
// It will return XXX or yyy or ZZZ 
// takes individual char as input and num of times to repeat
function _repeatString(char, num) {
    var _r = "";
    for (var o = 0; o < num; o++) {
        _r += char;
    }
    return _r
}
buildString('XyZ', 3)
```

[jsfiddle for Example](https://jsfiddle.net/42z0uvu1/5/)

Comment: Good question. Not intending to split hairs here, but your guess that the example of xyxzy would come out to xxxyyxxxzzzyyy should actually be xxxyyyxxxzzzyyy (missing one repetition of character y in the first instance).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds straight forward. You can run this in your browser's console:

```
var my = 'XyZ';

function repeat(str, times) {
  var res = '';
  for (var i in str) {
    var char = str[i];
    for (var j=0; j < times; j++) {
      res += char;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

var his = repeat(my, 3);
console.log(his);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    let valueCopy = str
    if (num > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
            valueCopy = valueCopy.concat(str)
        }
    } else {
        valueCopy = ""
    }
    return valueCopy;
}
repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

These days can be done a lot easier:

```js
    const repeater = (str, n) => [...str].map(c => c.repeat(n)).join('');
    alert(repeater('XyZ', 3));
```